# How to combine/merger two separate queries into one?

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-11

I have some old code that has very slow queries in one of the pages. There are two that caught my eye since they are very similar (almost identical). The only difference is one line in `WHERE CLAUSE`. Here is example:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT * -- Just for testing purpose I use * 
FROM Table 1
WHERE rec_id = #selected_id#
   <cfif userid is not "6">
       AND store_id = '#url.storedid#' -- I do not use cfqueryparam for testing purpuse
   </cfif>

-- Query 2
SELECT * -- Just for testing purpose I use * 
FROM Table 1
WHERE rec_id = #selected_id#
   <cfif userid is not "6">
       <cfif session.market_id is 4>
           AND store_id IN ('01','02','03')
       <cfelse>
           AND store_id = '#url.storedid#'
       </cfif>
   </cfif>
```

As you can see the only difference between these two queries are in `WHERE` clause inside of the `cfif` block. I was wondering if there is a way to put these two queries into one? The only column that is used two check the difference between two result sets is `TOTAL` column. If anyone have an idea of how this can be achieved please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's combined with ColdFusion. So basically back end language is used in WHERE clause.

Comment: First thing to do is put some queryparams around `selected_id` and `url.storedid`. And probably do some validation of those variables before they go to the query.  Also, what version of CF? Still CF11?

Comment: And where is `userid` coming from? Probably wouldn't hurt to scope that one too.

Comment: @Shawn I did put in my comments why cfqueryparams are not in there. I agree with your suggestions but first I'm trying to find the way to get only one query instead of two. Thank you.

Comment: Just saw that comment. Also, why trying to get to one query? What is the context? Both of those queries do two different things. For your first query, in the context, will it matter if `store_id` is `01`,`02`, or `03`. Also, what is the datatype of `store_id`? Is it a text type?

Comment: @Shawn There is a lot of redundant code. The only purpose of the second query is to get the sum of one column. That's why I was looking into options to merger if possible.

Comment: For example, in the first query, if your `userid` is 2 and your `session.market_id` is 4, do you want to limit your query to only `store_id` `01`,`02` and `03` even if your `url.storeid` is 6?

Comment: OK, that puts an entirely different context around what you are trying to do. So.... what completely are you trying to do with your final result? Are you able to provide more context of the code?

Comment: @Shawn The first query is used to display all the columns, second query is used only for this purpose: `variables.cost for(row in query2) { if(cost gt 0) {
      tot_cost = tot_cost + cost;
     }}` I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for the second query. Especially if it's to do looping of the original query  results. Again, if you can provide more context around what it is that you are trying to do, maybe provide some example data, it would be easier to get all the data you need in a single query. But see my questions above. Your second query is doing something slightly different than your first. What versions of both CF and database are you using?

Comment: @Shawn I use CF11 and Sybase database.

Comment: It looks like you're wanting an aggregate of the cost, but how do you want to divide that cost up? Are you just looking for cost of all of the entries? Does Query 2 relate to Query 1 in any way other than they have similar statements? For the question you asked, you essentially have 2 different filters in your queries, so your two queries can easily have two different result sets. Regardless, you don't want to aggregate a query in code when your query can do it much more efficiently. Without more context of the page, though, it's difficult to give an answer that will give you correct results.

Comment: Sybase does allow windowing functions, like `SUM(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ....)`, and that may be a way to get the aggregation you need.

Comment: And if your version doesn't have window functions, use correlated subqueries.

Comment: The other problem you mentioned, that led you to this question, is that you are trying to track down slow running queries. That can be affected by many, many things, and the very first thing you should look at to improve performance is to verify that proper indexes are on your tables. With proper indexes, neither of the above queries should have performance problems. They're fairly simple queries. How many records are you working with? Are you sure that it's a query issue and not network or database connection? Are you looping around either queiry and making multiple connections to the db?

Comment: To determine if the slowness is due to the query, start by copying the generated sql and looking at the execution plan in the database http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.stf.dmp.doc-SWS-2.0.0/projects/workspace/dmp/en/source/t_obtaining_an_execution_plan.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the best approach, but it will answer the question you asked which is how to achieve the same logic with a single query.

```
SELECT * -- Just for testing purpose I use * 
FROM Table 1
WHERE rec_id = #selected_id#
   <cfif userid is not "6" and session.market_id is 4>
           AND store_id IN ('01','02','03')
       <cfelseif userid is not "6">
           AND store_id = '#url.storedid#'    
   </cfif>
```

Bear in mind that this approach has slightly different logic because there is only one query variable.  The comments suggest that you might need two variables in which case this approach would work.

Query1 is the first one in your question.

```
<cfif userid is not "6" and session.market_id is 4>
<cfquery name = Query2 dbtype="query">
select *
from Query1
where store_id IN ('01','02','03')
</cfquery>
<cfelse>
<cfset Query2 = Query1>
</cfif>
```